# Need help adding autoscroll to this javascript code

Tags: javascript, autoscroll

I am using a free js file to paginate a news release page. It stays at the bottom after clicking the pagination link, and I'd like it to autoscroll back to the top of the page. Can someone tell me how to add that? I've tried adding various things I have found in other posts, but obviously I don't know what I'm doing and nothing has worked. Thanks in advance.

```
/*global console, document, $, jQuery */
(function ($) {
'use strict';

function log(d) {
    console.log(d);
}

//    $(document).ready(function () {

$.fn.pagination = function (options) {
    //        alert('prout');
    var paginationContainer = this,
        itemsPerPage,
        itemsToPaginate,
        defaults,
        settings,
        i,

        numberOfPaginationLinks;

    log(paginationContainer);

    defaults = {
        itemsPerPage: 5
    };

    settings = {};

    $.extend(settings, defaults, options);

    itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;

    itemsToPaginate = $(settings.itemsToPaginate);
    numberOfPaginationLinks = Math.ceil((itemsToPaginate.length / 
   itemsPerPage));
    log(numberOfPaginationLinks);

    // Création de list dans la div ciblée
    $('<ul></ul>').prependTo(paginationContainer);






    // Boucle qui créer des li
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfPaginationLinks; i += 1) {
        paginationContainer.find('ul').append('<li>' + (i + 1) + 
   '</li>');
    }

    itemsToPaginate.filter(':gt(' + (itemsPerPage - 1) + ')').hide();

    paginationContainer.find('ul li').click(function () {

        var itemsToHide,
            linkNumber,
            itemsToShow,
            $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass(settings.activeClass);
        $this.siblings().removeClass(settings.activeClass);

        linkNumber = $this.text();

        itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(':lt(' + ((linkNumber - 1) * 
        itemsPerPage) + ')');

        $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(':gt(' + ((linkNumber 
        * itemsPerPage) - 1) + ')'));

        itemsToHide.hide();

        itemsToShow = itemsToPaginate.not(itemsToHide);
        itemsToShow.show();

        });
   };
     //    });

         }(jQuery));
```

I want the page to start at the top each time you go to the next page, but currently it stays at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are scrolling the window:

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
```

eg

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

If you are scrolling inside an element with overflow: auto/scroll do it like so:

```
var e = document.getElementById('containerDiv');
e.scrollTop = 0;
```

it loks nicer if you add this css attribute to your scrolling element

```
body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried adding what you submitted and it took away the pagination altogether (using my element - which is container - instead of containerDiv). I'm guessing there is some formatting I'm missing. Sorry, I don't know JS so it's a whole new thing for me.

Comment: Figuren out what Container ist scrolling, give it an Attribute id="containerDiv" andere then rund that Code.

Comment: Try paginationContainer.scrollTop=0;

Comment: Both break the pagination. Do I add it to the js file exactly as you have it?

Comment: Break? What dies this mean? What dies Tour console say?

Comment: ....Does your console say, i meant. Sry just reinstalled my phone....autocorrection of default keyboard.

Comment: Not a problem lol. By break I just mean the pagination numbers go away and all the news stories are listed instead of just 5.

Comment: Hm, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I've never done that before but will see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Can't seem to figure that out either. I'll quit taking up your time now and try and do some more research and come back when I can not be quite so ignorant. I appreciate your trying to help.

Comment: Got it! Just had to put your code in the right place in the JS document! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you figured it out ;). Now i am waiting for my somewhat advanced issue for dome advise, in between i am helping others were i can. If you add that css it should scroll smoothly and not instantly.

Comment: I will. Thanks again!